# Different Retry objects based on error type spring WebFlux

Tags: spring, spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I've written a Web client to interact with some external service using spring project-reactor. The external service sometimes throttles incoming requests. How can I provide different Retry types based on the different responses/exceptions?

For Instance:

1. If it is a response with a 429 error code, create a Retry object with the duration provided in the response header (e.g retry-after), or else,
2. If it is some other exception, for example 5XX, then retry with exponential backoff:

   `Retry.backoff(MAX_ATTEMPTS, Duration.ofMillis(MILLIS))`

The client API call code is:

```
            .bodyValue(inputQuery)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(QueryResult.class)
            .retryWhen(customStrategy)
            .doOnError(ex -> log.debug("API invocation error: ", ex));
```

customStrategy can will have the logic to decide which Retry object to create. Is there anyway we can achieve this?

Comment: Please share the solution if you find it..

Answer (score 1):

You can specify more than one `.retryWhen` in the statement and create your `Retry` objects with the appropriate `filter`s.

Something like that:

```java
.bodyToMono(String.class)
.retryWhen(
        Retry
                .backoff(3, Duration.ofSeconds(5))
                .filter(throwable -> throwable instanceof WebClientResponseException.TooManyRequests)
)
.retryWhen(
        Retry
                .fixedDelay(3, Duration.ofSeconds(1))
                .filter(throwable -> ((WebClientResponseException) throwable).getStatusCode().is5xxServerError())
)
.block();
```

Here, you can customize your Filter and Retry objects any way you want.